# Cocoa window resize information

Tags: macos, cocoa, resize, window

I want to implement edge snapping of windows in cocoa. For this I need to either
 (a) get info about which side or corner the user is dragging (plus the key modifiers shift and option), or
 (b) implement resizing myself

Don't seem to find a way to do (a) and the problem with (b) is that I need to be able to catch a click a few pixels outside the window frame, which again I don't know how to do.

Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research shows that there's no way to do this directly. So I resorted to infer the corner/edges based on mouse position[1] and a few hard-coded metrics, which will have to be adjusted if OSX window frames will look different enough in future versions.

[1] See function resize_area_hit() in https://github.com/luapower/nw/blob/master/nw_cocoa.lua.